# Scala how to pass entire list in function?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

In a function like this:

```
def row(line: List[String]): Row = { Row(line(0), line(1), line(2), line(3).toInt, line(4), line(5), line(6), line(7), line(8), line(9)) }
```

Rather than list out each element of the `List`, is there a concise way to send all List elements as parameters? Something like:

```
def row(line: List[String]): Row = { Row(line.foreach) }
```

This would be helpful when we don't know the size of the List being passed in.

In Golang, there is a dot dot dot function: `arrayName...` that accomplishes this. Wondering if there is a way to do the same in Scala.

Comment: Please don't tag spam.  This question has nothing to do with [tag:java].

Comment: What is `.toInt` at specific parameters?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `Row` is the `Row` from Spark, you can splat into a `Row`:

```
scala> def row(l: List[String]): Row = Row(l:_*)
row: (l: List[String])org.apache.spark.sql.Row

scala> row(List("a","b","c"))
res1: org.apache.spark.sql.Row = [a,b,c]
```

(`:_*` requires a variable number of arguments.) You'd have to deal with the conversion to an `Int` separately.

Answer (score 0):

If `Row` is a case class, I can think of two ways of doing it.

One way would be to pattern match over `line`

```
case class Row(a: Int, b: Int, c: Int)

val line = List(1, 2, 3)

def row(line: List[Int]): Row = line match {
  case List(a, b, c) => Row(a, b, c)
}
row(line)
// Row(1, 2, 3)
```

The second one would be using a tuple instead of a list:

```
case class Row(a: Int, b: Int, c: Int)

val line = (1, 2, 3)

def row(line: (Int, Int, Int)): Row = Row.tupled(line)

row(line)
// Row(1,2,3)
```

If `Row` is indeed a case class, I would recommend creating some abstraction instead of initializing the class with 10 member variables

If `Row` is a type alias, you can use `*` to *unpack* the args list and then  `:_*`, that is type declaration for `vararg` (variable-length argument list)

```
type Row = List[Int]

def row(xs: Int*) = List(xs:_*)

row(1, 2, 3)
// List(1, 2, 3)

val line = List(1, 2, 3)

row(line:_*)
// List(1, 2, 3)
```